# Slider id selector not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, jquery-selectors, slider

I'm trying to select a slider and retrieve the value from it but it throws undefined.
Here's the html code for the slider and the collapsible containing the slider:

```
<div id=collapsible'+element[0].id+' class="collapsible_contains_slider" slider_id='+element[0].id+' data-role="collapsible-set" data-theme="a" data-content-theme="c">
    <div data-role="collapsible" data-collapsed="false">
        <h3 id="title_collapsible">'+image.pname+'</h3>

        <center>
            <div id=image_cesta><img src=data:imajpeg;base64,'+image.pimage+' alt="image"></div>
            <div data-role="fieldcontain"></div>
        </center>

        <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">Cantidad: <input type="range" class="sliderscesta" id=slider_into_collapsible slider_value='+element[0].id+' name="slider" value='+element[1].value+' min="0" max="100" data-highlight="true">
        </fieldset>

        <div class="ui-grid-a">
            <div class="ui-block-a">
                <a id="delete_product_cesta_page" type="hidden" idproductecesta='+element[0].id+' data-role="button" data-theme="a"> Delete product</a>
            </div><div class="ui-block-b" id="reset_button_slider_cesta"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<br><br>
```

[image]

And here my Javascript code to select the slider and retrieve the value:

```
$('#cesta_page').on( 'slidestop', function( event ) {
    button_delete_or_update($('#slider_into_collapsible').attr('slider_value'),'update');
});
```

Comment: It looks like you could possibly have duplicate id's

Comment: Could you add a link?

Comment: there are cases inside that string where you are using an attribute without quotes that includes a space, that isn't valid. For example, `<img src=data:imajpeg;base64, '+image.pimage+' alt="image">`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```
$(document).on( 'slidestop', '[type="range"]',function( event ) {
    alert($(this).attr('slider_value'));
});
```

Of course it will work on sliders that have attribute **`slider_value`**. If you want to use it on elements having only attribute **`slider_value`** use this:

```
$(document).on( 'slidestop', '[type="range"]',function( event ) {
    if($(this).attr('slider_value').length > 0) {
         alert($(this).attr('slider_value'));
    }
});
```

Comment: why '[type="range"]' ? Thanks :)

Comment: You want to bind slidestop to a slider input element and tha element has a type range, like this type="range". Look at your HTML.